# Disable the animation/transition on the mobile

Tags: javascript, css

I want a menu with a dropdown submenu with animation/transition, but not mobile. I used CSS to disable the animation/transition on the mobile version. When you click on the hamburger, all the menus show up with no animation/transition, but when you click to close the hamburger, the animation shows up, see the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HGZB.jpg)

```js
function mvFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "main-nav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "main-nav";
  }
}
```

```css
a:hover {
  transition: color .5s;
}

header {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
}

#header-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#nav-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.icon-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.header-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  stroke: currentColor;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  fill: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

a .header-icon-outside {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.header-icon-outside {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  stroke: currentColor;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  fill: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#myTopnav {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 75px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.main-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.main-nav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #DBAC34;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-nav .dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.main-nav .dropbtn {
  color: #DBAC34;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 17px 12px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.main-nav .dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 145px;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.main-nav .dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #DBAC34;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  display: block;
}

.main-nav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.main-nav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.main-nav .dropdown-content hr {
  height: 1px;
  border-width: 0;
  background-color: #DBAC34;
  margin: 0px 15px;
}

.main-nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0.0s;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #DBAC34;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main-nav a,
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-nav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .main-nav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main-nav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .main-nav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .main-nav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .main-nav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
    transition-property: none;
    transform: none;
    transition: none;
    z-index: 200;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .main-nav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="page-wrap">
    <header>
      <div id="header-wrap">
        <div id="nav-wrap">

          <nav class="main-nav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="#!"> Page 1 </a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn"> Page 2</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#!">sub 1</a>
                <hr />
                <a href="#!">sub 2</a>
                <hr />
                <a href="#!l">sub 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#!"> Page 3 </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="mvFunction()">
              <div class="bar1"></div>
              <div class="bar2"></div>
              <div class="bar3"></div>
            </a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

version. When you click on the hamburger, all the menus show up with no animation/transition, but when you click to close the hamburger, the animation shows up, see the image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smt3V.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing the issue

```
  .main-nav .dropdown-content {
transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

yes you have written  CSS to disable this transition, but there is a `.resposive` class, when you click on the hamburger this `.responsive` class gets removed, so the below code is useless

```
.main-nav.responsive .dropdown-content {
   transition : none
}
```

to fix this write CSS without this`.responsiv`e selector like

```
.main-nav .dropdown-content {
   transition : none
 }
```